# NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener помогите понять

Tags: java, android

У меня выдает такую ошибку

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/*********/base.apk:classes5.dex)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:441)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at ru.prezident.ghazaryans.prezidentmed.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Не могу найти где ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста,вот gradle файл

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*******"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    //for server
    //for imagesuploade
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: очень похоже на конфликт библиотек, в вашем проекте несколько разных версий одной и той же либы

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а как исправить , можете подсказать ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies находите разные версии той библиотеки где содержится данный класс, на котором возникает исключение, а далее делаете exclude этой библиотеки из зависимостей к которой она принадлежит и если все будет хорошо то ошибка пропадет

Comment: Посмотрите свои либы подключенные из github, скорее всего они содержат ссылки на `com.android.support:support-v4` и исключайте методом указанным @ArtemKonovalov

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Огромное спасибо вы спасли меня))))))